# Solving ambiguous input: mismatched input

Tags: antlr4

I have this grammar:

```
grammar MkSh;

script
  : (statement
    | targetRule
    )*
  ;

statement
  :  assignment
  ;

assignment
  :  ID '=' STRING
  ;

targetRule
  : TARGET ':' TARGET*
  ;

ID
  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
  ;

WS
  : ( ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    ) -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;

STRING
  : '\"' CHR* '\"'
  ;

fragment
CHR
  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|' ')
  ;

TARGET
  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'-'|'/'|'.')+
  ;
```

and this input file:

```
hello="world"

target: CLASSES
```

When running my parser I'm getting this error:

```
line 3:6 mismatched input ':' expecting '='
line 3:15 mismatched input ';' expecting '='
```

Which is because of the parser is taking "target" as an ID instead of a TARGET. I want the parser to choose the rule based on the separator character (':' vs '=').

How can I get that to happen?

(This is my first Antlr project so I'm open to anything.)

Comment: I suppose though Antlr syntax makes it look like there's one big set of rules, lexical analysis is still really a separate task under the covers. So the parsing rules that know about colons and equal signs have essentially no knowledge of the lexing rules that decide whether the string "target" should be tokenized as an ID or a TARGET. One of a great many solutions is to define a relaxed token that subsumes both TARGET and ID, then check in your actions whether the token contains any illegal characters for the context. This also allows finer error messages ("no '/' allowed in assignment ID").

Comment: @RonBurk Could you elaborate on how I would create such a setup? Or point me to where I could find an example? Thanks for a useful comment anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know that the word *target* is matched as a *ID* token and not as a *TARGET* token, and since you have written the rule *ID* before *TARGET*,  it will always be  recognized as *ID* by the lexer. Notice that the word *target* completely complies to both *ID* and *TARGET* lexer rule, (I'm going to suppose that you are writing a laguage), meaning that the *target* which is a keyword can also be used as an id. In the book - "The definitive ANTLR reference" there is a subtitle "Treating Keywords As Identifiers" that deals with exactely these kinds of issues. I suggest you take a look at that. Or if you prefer the quick answer the solution is to use lexer modes. Also would be better to split grammar into parser and lexer grammar.

Answer (score 1):

As @cantSleepNow alludes to, you've defined a token (TARGET) that is a lexical superset of another token (ID), and then told the lexer to only tokenize a string as TARGET if it *cannot* be tokenized as ID. All made more obscure by the fact that ANTLR lexing rules look like ANTLR parsing rules, though they are really quite different beasts.

(Warning: writing off the top of my head without testing :-)

Your real project might be more complex, but in the possibly simplified example you posted, you could defer distinguishing the two to the parsing phase, instead of distinguishing them in the lexer:

```
id : TARGET
    { complain if not legal identifier (e.g., contains slashes, etc.) }
    ;
assignment
  :  id '=' STRING
  ;
```

Seems like that would solve the lexing issue, and allow you to give a more intelligent error message than "syntax error" when a user gets the syntax for ID wrong. The grammar remains ambiguous, but maybe ANTLR roulette will happen to make the choice you prefer in the ambiguous case. Of course, unambiguous grammers tend to make for languages that humans find more readable, and now you can see why the classic `makefile` syntax **requires** a newline after an assignment or target rule.

Comment: Thanks for the Makefile reference. My project is very close to a Make clone :)